# Como condicionar sweetalert para que solo aparezca una vez cuando le doy clic al boton de cancelar

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hola de nuevo mi duda es como puedo realizar que mi sweetalert solo se muestre una vez, ya que ahora como esta me carga cada que ingreso a una pagina determinada y desearia que solo se muestre una vez al entrar a esa pagina y las demas veces ya no... como podria lograrlo?

anexo el codigo del script

```
  <script>
                    function load() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST', //forma en que lo estas pasando
                            data: 'key='+1,  //parametros serializados
                            url: 'services/ConsultaNotificacion.php', // url del archivo q va a procesar los datos
        
                            success: function(response) //si la respuesta es exitosa
                            {
                                console.log(response);
                                var resultado=JSON.parse(response);//parseamos el resultado a JSON
                                if(resultado.respuesta == "exitoso"){//comparamos si lo que tien
                                Swal.fire({
                                    title: 'Usted Tiene Nuevos Cambios por aprobar',
                                    text: "Desea aprobarlos?",
                                    icon: 'warning',
                                    showCancelButton: true,
                                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                    confirmButtonText: 'Aprobar!'
            
                                }).then((result) => {
                                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                    window.location.href = "cambios.php";//redirigimos a index despues de 3 segundos
               
                                    }
              
                                    })
    

                                }
                             }

                            });
                        }
                            window.onload = load;
                </script>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que tu buscas es que se muestre una única vez en la vida y luego ya nunca más? Pregunto, porque es lo que describes, pero es un comportamiento que no es tan común eso que buscas...

Comment: lo que pasa es que asi como esta cada que entro a la pagina me muestra la alerta si tengo un registro

Comment: Deberías guardar en algún lado que la alerta ya se mostró, ya sea en cookie, localStorage o, del lado del servidor. Cada que entres a la página analizas ese dato y muestras la alerta solo si no existe.

Comment: @jachguate Es que estoy implementando una funcionalidad para que el administrador pueda aprobar o rechazar cambios que otro usuario realiza en unos registros, entonces los listo en una tabla con sus botones de permitir y rechazar, Cuando hay un nuevo registro dentro de la tabla le envio un mensaje al administrador cuando se loguea que le dice que tiene nuevos cambios por aprobar, el problema viene en que mientras esos cambios no los apruebe, siempre le muestra al usuario el mensaje cuando se va al home del sistema y quisiera condicionarlo para que si el administrador le da en ignorar se oculte

Comment: Por favor alguna idea? se me ocurre con una bandera pero la verdad no soy muy experto con ellas

Comment: Suponiendo que dichas autorizaciones tienen un ID que va creciendo, puedes guardar el ID de la última autorización que mostraste y cambiar la lógica para mostrar el mensaje o alerta solo si el nuevo ID que llega es mayor al almacenado. Esto puedes guardarlo del lado del cliente (en una cookie o en localstorage) o del lado del servidor. De esta manera le dices que hay nuevos solo cuando realmente hay nuevos.

Comment: @WalterLopezCruz pudiste resolverlo? yo tambien estoy tratando de implementar lo mismo

Comment: @jesus_san1 No, tuve que cambiar mi tipo de alerta de sweetalert a un tipo **Push** que se desaparece luego de unos segundos....

Comment: @WalterLopezCruz usaste notificaciones push en tu sistema? y si lo usaste, que libreria usaste?